# Angular 5 uglifying build returns error

Tags: javascript, angular, uglifyjs

I updated my SPA from Angular 4 to Angular 5 with all dependencies. Works so far so good. The dev and prod builds work very well. No errors or warnings.

When I build the SPA with `--prod` flag, `angular-cli` uglifies the build. No errors from `angular-cli`. But when I open my SPA in my browser, I have an error and nothing happens. The page doesn't load at all (only loading spinner).

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'Ie' imported by the module 't'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
at c (compiler.js:466)
at compiler.js:15088
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at t.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15071)
at t.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:14998)
at compiler.js:15086
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at t.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15071)
at t._loadModules (compiler.js:33486)
at t._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:33447)
```

Here is my `package.json` with all dependencies and my build script:

```
{
    "name": "broadcast-manager",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "dev": "ng serve --dev --environment main --port 1337 --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
        "prod": "ng build --prod --environment main --aot false"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.1",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.1",
        "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^6.1.0",
        "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.0.4",
        "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
        "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
        "core-js": "^2.5.1",
        "d3": "^4.11.0",
        "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
        "moment": "^2.19.2",
        "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
        "ngx-chips": "^1.5.9",
        "node-sass": "^4.6.1",
        "protractor": "^5.2.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "tslint": "^5.8.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
    },
    "devDependencies": {}
}
```

And here is my `.angular-cli.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "broadcast"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "../public/frontend",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        ".htaccess",
        "favicon.ico",
        {
  "glob": "**/*",
  "input": "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/",
  "output": "./assets/fonts/"
}
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "prefix": "bm-",
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "main": "environments/environment.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ],
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {
    }
  },
  "warnings": {
    "typescriptMismatch": false
  }
}
```

How can I debug what's happening/what's going wrong?

Comment: i think it may be due to version changing, did you had a look on  that matter?

Comment: Nowhere found any issue like mine. At least not yet.

Comment: Someone reported this issue on the Angular CLI Github  [repo](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8505), perhaps it is related?

Comment: I had similar error, when i used angular-material and some other angular package. It was due to version change from 4 to 5 in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem with following, easy solution, thanks to @Kevin RED.

Before:

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "ng build --prod --aot false"
}
```

After:

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "ng build --prod --aot false --build-optimizer=false"
}
```

I'm not sure right now what the functionality of `build-optimizer` is ([npmjs-build-optimizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer)), but if I set it to `true`, I receive an error. Set on `false` and it works.